# How to search for email from contact by name with mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

I see it is very easy to find email from sender if I type part of the email address of the contact.

```
mu find contact:address
```

However, having to remember parts of email addresses is kind of like having to remember phone numbers. It's particularly convenient and it feels pretty backwards for 21st century email use. I know mu has access to the strings corresponding to the real names because it shows them in the headers buffer in mu4e.

Is there some way to search those?

Answer (score 0):

`mu cfind name` does what you want.

Not sure what you're asking about mu4e as completion works as intended with either name or email to me.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I already knew about `mu cfind`. However, using `mu cfind` only lets you search for email addresses given contact names. It doesn't let you conveniently search for emails from contacts with those names. To make that work, you have to do a two step search. First find all the emails which match the contacts. Then insert those emails into a mu find command. I was hoping there would be a one step search. If that is impossible, I would accept an example showing how to do the two step search programmatically.

Comment: I'm not sure about understanding your question, as what I understand seems covered by `cfind`. A practical example will help.

Comment: I don't want to find the email addresses of contacts. I want to find particular email messages from contacts given only their name. I don't want to have to worry about knowing their email addresses up front. That is a tedious and distracting intermediate step which at least GMail keeps me from having to think about.

Comment: Still can't figure it, if I search witn mu4e using `from:alfonso` returns the emails I have having alfonso either in name or email. Same if ask for `from:alf*`, broadening the resultset (at least potentially). Seems to fulfill such kind of search. what I'm missing?  mu4e 1.8.10, BTW

Comment: That could be it. I'm still using 1.6.11.